# What is the minimum Linux kernel version a Comet Lake-S CPU can run on?

Tags: debian, intel

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a Comet Lake-S system on a Debian Stretch install with kernel 4.9.0 or 4.19 from backports.
I'm only refering to CPU and chipset (B460) compatibility - I'm aware that there's no iGPU support before 5.x, which wouldn't be necessary anyway.

Comment: The answer is 99.99% yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: it doesn't work, the kernel halts.

Comment: That's weird - you could probably file a bug report. Basic CPU support must absolutely be there - after all, all x86 compatible CPUs have the same basic architecture.